# How to take full database backup using CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm working on a CodeIgniter 4 project where I have to provide the functionality to take the full backup of the currently connected database with CodeIgniter 4.
But CodeIgniter is showing an error mentioned below.

**CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException #8
Unsupported feature of the database platform you are using.**

I want to integrate it as same as CodeIgniter 3 provides.

I wrote the below line of code to my Controller

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$util = \Config\Database::Utils($db);
$util->backup([
    'format' => 'gzip',
    'filename' => 'backup' . date('Y-m-d')
]);
```

But it is a throwing exception. An error screenshot is also attached.
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZT0z.png)

I have gone through many solutions, but they are only limited to the particular table. But I want to export the whole database at the moment.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/issues/1257#issuecomment-680097552): _At this point there are not plans to support database backups through the framework._

Comment: @InsiteFX, one of the supermoderators of the CI-forum suggests [here](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-78818.html) to have a look at [this](https://github.com/daniloaz/myphp-backup)